# Opening pdf in DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a pdf file uploaded from the filemanager, this file must be shown in a new tab when a user clicks on the download button.

For now I just create the link manually, because I don't know how else I could do it. 
Is there any other way to do this (for example via the settings page)?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a link to the PDF in the DNN Navigation Menu by adding a new Page, but in the URL options for the page point to the PDF file, instead of an actual DNN page.